# How to create an empty zip file in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, zip

I have a scenario where I must first create a zip file, and after, when my files arrive from another location, they will be added into the zip.

This second part is done with the `-u` parameter:

```
zip -u {{project}}.zip {{file}}
```

`--help` for this command isn't quite helpful either:

```
user@host:~# zip --help
Copyright (c) 1990-2008 Info-ZIP - Type 'zip "-L"' for software license.
Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008). Usage:
zip [-options] [-b path] [-t mmddyyyy] [-n suffixes] [zipfile list] [-xi list]
  The default action is to add or replace zipfile entries from list, which
  can include the special name - to compress standard input.
  If zipfile and list are omitted, zip compresses stdin to stdout.
  -f   freshen: only changed files  -u   update: only changed or new files
  -d   delete entries in zipfile    -m   move into zipfile (delete OS files)
  -r   recurse into directories     -j   junk (don't record) directory names
  -0   store only                   -l   convert LF to CR LF (-ll CR LF to LF)
  -1   compress faster              -9   compress better
  -q   quiet operation              -v   verbose operation/print version info
  -c   add one-line comments        -z   add zipfile comment
  -@   read names from stdin        -o   make zipfile as old as latest entry
  -x   exclude the following names  -i   include only the following names
  -F   fix zipfile (-FF try harder) -D   do not add directory entries
  -A   adjust self-extracting exe   -J   junk zipfile prefix (unzipsfx)
  -T   test zipfile integrity       -X   eXclude eXtra file attributes
  -y   store symbolic links as the link instead of the referenced file
  -e   encrypt                      -n   don't compress these suffixes
  -h2  show more help
```

Comment: Nothing dirty about that, because these two commands are *scriptable*.  Dirty would be doing it manually with WinZip.  
The reason this came in handy for me is because I'm working with Terraform to create and deploy a ZIP file.  The lambda_function definition has a function call to filebase64sha256('lambda.zip'), and on initial run, it doesn't yet exist.  So, I'm checking in an empty 22-byte zipfile to my git repo, so that when it runs for the first time, the filebase64sha256() func won't crash with "file not found".  
Thanks for your post!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done it the dirty way:

Created an file called `emptyfile` with one byte in it (whitespace).

Then I added that file into the zip file:

```
zip -q {{project}}.zip emptyfile
```

To finally remove it:

```
zip -dq {{project}}.zip emptyfile
```

(if `-q` is omitted, you will get warning: `zip warning: zip file empty`)

This way I've got an empty zip file one can `-u`pdate.

All that can be converted to a oneliner (idea from GaspardP):

```
echo | zip -q > {{project}}.zip && zip -dq {{project}}.zip -
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: (nota: I've converted an attempt to answer in the question itself into a community wiki).

Comment: Thanks! For anyone looking for a one liner: `echo | zip -q > {{project}}.zip && zip -dq {{project}}.zip -`

Comment: Great idea @gaspardp. Answer updated